# Android: How to return to previous app after closing notification dialog

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-dialog

Am currently launching a dialog on receiving a broadcasted alert.  I am doing this by starting an activity, which immediately opens a dialog:

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderNotificationActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    . . .

public class ReminderNotificationActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ReminderNotificationDialog dialog = new ReminderNotificationDialog(this, reminder);
        dialog.show();
    }
    . . .
```

However when I close the dialog:

```
ReminderNotificationDialog.this.dismiss();
parentActivity.finish();
```

I am taken back to the last screen that I visited in MY application.  Whereas I'd like to return to wherever I was on the android device when the notification fired. **EVEN IF THAT SCREEN IS IN ANOTHER APPLICATION**.

e.g. if I was on the android home screen then return there. If I was in chrome browsing a web page when the notification fired, then return there.  If I was in my own app on a certain page, then return there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't finish your parent activity. Comment this line `parentActivity.finish();`

Comment: Y dont you take that actvity themed as dialog??

Comment: user3110424, I want to return to which-ever screen I was on before my activity/dialog was launched.  Be that in my app, or another totally different app, or the android home screen.  Would not calling finish() on my own Activity accomplish this?

Comment: Activity themed as dialog?  Sorry, what do you mean by that??

Comment: Have you try to finish only the current Activity when the work on notification done?@Ben

Answer (score 0):

*Almost* worked this out by playing around with the intent flags.

If I start with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK flag, when I call finish() on my activity, the previous application is brought to the foreground.

i.e.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

However, this method fails in that if I'm in my own application when the notification fires, when I close the dialog, I am taken back to the home screen.  Whereas preferably I would be taken back to wherever I was in my own app.